# STM32 proteus simulation doesn't work properly

Tags: simulation, stm32f1, proteus, bluepill

guys I'm making a simulation for stm32f103c6 the code written on Arduino IDE. I'm testing a simple LED blink on proteus and it's not even working.

[Arduino Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzWWA.png)

[And this is what happens when I run the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kvN6.png)

I'm sure that I Exported .hex file from Arduino IDE and STM32 board manager is installed on my Arduino boards manager.